# Moodle Sessions Error Preventing Admin User Creation on Fresh Install

Tags: moodle, moodle-api

While installing Moodle, in https://mylms.com/user/editadvanced.php?id=2, after filling out the form to create the first admin account, the page redirects to give the following error message "Your session has most likely timed out. Please log in again.".

No idea what the problem might be.

- Using:
  Ubuntu 22.04
  MariaDB v15.1
  PHP 8.1

Thank you in advance.

I have checked all the database tables to ensure they are not damaged. I have plenty of storage left on the system (approx 500 GB empty). I get the same issue while attempting to install Moodle v4.2+ and v4.1+.

I haven't found anything close to this issue on the Moodle developers forum or on StackOverflow, etc.

Comment: StackOverflow is dedicated to solving `if/then/else` programming code (and tools) problems. Your question seems to be about using and configuring moodle/mariaDb. It may be more appropriate to post at [su] or if this is for a production system, [sf]. Please read their help sections about on-topic questions and how-to-ask. Please delete here and post there. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Can you add debugging to display the trace, then copy and paste the trace into the question

Edit `config.php` and add

```
// Force a debugging mode regardless the settings in the site administration
@error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT); // NOT FOR PRODUCTION SERVERS!
@ini_set('display_errors', '1');    // NOT FOR PRODUCTION SERVERS!
$CFG->debug = (E_ALL | E_STRICT);   // === DEBUG_DEVELOPER - NOT FOR PRODUCTION SERVERS!
$CFG->debugdisplay = 1;             // NOT FOR PRODUCTION SERVERS!
```